# Is it possible to reference a Template name dynamically and call onRedered on it

Tags: meteor

Currently I have the following in a package:

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function() {
  //Do stuff when the template called "layout" is rendered
});
```

But I would like to make the template name user configurable. Something like:

```
var templateName = 'customLayout'; 
Template.{templateName}.onRendered(function() {
  //Do stuff when the template called "customLayout" is rendered
});
```

Any help in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use the square brackets syntax to do that:

```js
Template['customLayout'].onRendered( [...] )
```

`'customLayout'` above can be an arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 0):

From Meteor 0.8.2, you can write this:

```
var myTemplate='foo';
{{> UI.dynamic template=myTemplate}}
```

https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

Comment: This is to used to render a dynamic template.  I need to call 'onRendered' on a dynamic template.

Comment: `UI.dynamic` is nowadays called `Template.dynamic`.